# Остановить смещение элемента от левого края

Tags: html, css, position

Есть элементы которые адаптируются под разное разрешение, так вот размеры width я ограничил функциями min и max, но у меня также стоит смещение от левого края тоже в процентах, как ограничить его? Чтобы после определенного размера страницы, он перестал смешаться и оставался в том же положении сколько бы его ни уменьшали. А также останавливался на максимуме и на больших разрешениях не увеличивался еще.

```css
#rectanglePN {
    width: 13.6842105%;
    min-width: 187px;
    max-width: 260px;
    height: 17px;
    
    background: green;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    
    top: 140px;
    left: 16.9%;
    min-left: 170px; /* Несуществующее свойство */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Случаи когда верстка меняется в зависимости от разрешения устройства обычно решаются с помощью [медиа запросов](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media).

То есть сначала задаем обычное правило:

```
#rectanglePN {
    /*остальные свойства*/
    left: 16.9%;
}
```

Потом правила для всяких "ненормальных" размеров и типов устройств:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1000px) { 
    #rectanglePN{
        left: 170px; 
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1470px){
    #rectanglePN{
        left: 250px;
    }
}
```